# Unable to run Python script in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am using Azure VM with Windows 10. I installed SQL Server 2017 and Management Studio 18.4

I executed this script:

```
EXEC sp_configure  'external scripts enabled', 1  
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

[image]

So looks env is ready to execute my python script. However I get an error:

[image]

https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2018/08/29/sql-python-error-sp_execute_external_script-is-disabled-on-this-instance-of-sql-server-use-sp_configure-external-scripts-enabled-to-enable-it/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/security/firewall-configuration?view=sql-server-2017

I am following above links to resolve.

I feel since I am on Azure VM firewall may be challenge but reading MS doc its not clear what changes I need to make/ check in firewall

Checked Services also, all are up and running:

[image]

[image]

[image: Win]

Comment: Did you Google/Bing your error: *sql server unable to launch runtime for 'Python' script*? Quite a bit of hits that suggest permission issues. One link suggests: giving the service an administrator account to run under or specifically adding NT SERVICE\MSSQLLaunchPad user to local "Administrators" user group.

Comment: yes @Parfait, that has also been tried with no success

Comment: Well, keep searching as it has worked for some posters among other fixes. Also, this is more a DBA Exchange or ServerFault/Superuser Exchange question since it involves your CPU/server environment. Not much a coding question for StackOverflow and not much we can diagnose/test on our end.

Comment: Just to clarify; you use a "normal" Windows 10 VM in Azure, on which you have installed SQL Server 2017, and SSMS? After the installation of SQL, has there been any OS upgrades, or SQL Server upgrades?

Comment: @NielsBerglund windows updates snapshots also added now.  And yes. its normal Azure VM with Win 10. Then I installed SQL server and SSMS manually

Comment: When you installed SQL Server did you remember to tick "Machine Learning Services (In-Database)" and "Python" on the Feature Selection page? They are not ticked by default.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you are correct. Python was unchecked . Its resolved now.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning not sure how to promote your comment as Answer